# Logging framework for UI?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a good framework to log UI errors and view them.

Is there anyway we can store a frontend logs, console.info, console.errors, console.log etc in their respective files?

Our project hugely relies on UI and a good logging system would help.

Can you please share your experience regarding the same?

Comment: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js

Answer (score 1):

`Raven` (in comments) is a great choice. If you want something quick and dirty, you can use an AJAX call to log errors like this (assumes jQuery, can be easily done with plain JS too):

```
var logClientError = function(error){
    var data = {'error':error, 'extra':'More context'}
    var options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, {
        data : $.param(data, true),
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'url/to/log/errors'  // points to a view that can write errors to server log or database or alert your
    });
    $.ajax(opt);
};
```

```
// Usage
try {
    // my code
}
catch(e) {
    logClientError(e)
}
```

Comment: looks like this is a paid library is it? Correct me if i am wrong. When i go to their website they are asking for a subscription

Comment: Yes but they have a free tier that's limited to a single user and 250 events per day